# mysql join another table's rows as columns in the query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:  users and user_meta.  I would like to get all of the user's meta rows in the same query as the regular user info.  How can I join the rows of the user_meta table that would work sort of as columns in the first table?

user_meta: user_id(int 15), context(varchar 250), value(varchar 250)

```
       SELECT 
             m.user_id AS id, m.member_group_id, m.avatar_id, m.display_name, m.email_address, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.join_date) AS join_date, m.status,
             l.member_id, COUNT(l.member_id) AS total_listings,
             g.group_id, g.title AS group_title,
             a.attachment_id, a.file_path AS avatar_path
        FROM users AS m
        LEFT JOIN user_meta AS meta ON m.user_id = meta.user_id
        LEFT JOIN listings AS l ON l.member_id = m.user_id
        LEFT JOIN groups AS g ON m.member_group_id = g.group_id
        LEFT JOIN attachments AS a ON m.avatar_id = a.attachment_id
        WHERE m.user_id = ".$id."
        GROUP BY m.user_id
        LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

simply try this   `m.user_id AS id ORDER BY ASC`

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your question.
You mention 2 tables: users & metadata but on query example you have table listings, groups and attachments. 
For which metadata field you whant to sort?

Keep in mind that for count(l.member_id) to work you will have to group by for all others fields:

```
Group by  m.user_id , m.member_group_id, m.avatar_id, m.display_name, m.email_address, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.join_date), m.status,
             l.member_id,  g.group_id, g.title ,
             a.attachment_id, a.file_path
```

If you do't want to group by all other field, you have to create a subquery, something like example below, where a subquery was for count.

```
SELECT 
             m.user_id AS id, m.member_group_id, m.avatar_id, m.display_name, m.email_address, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.join_date) AS join_date, m.status,
             l.member_id, 

(select COUNT(l.member_id) from listings where listings.member_id=m.user_id)  AS total_listings,

             g.group_id, g.title AS group_title,
             a.attachment_id, a.file_path AS avatar_path
        FROM users AS m
        LEFT JOIN user_meta AS meta ON m.user_id = meta.user_id
        LEFT JOIN listings AS l ON l.member_id = m.user_id
        LEFT JOIN groups AS g ON m.member_group_id = g.group_id
        LEFT JOIN attachments AS a ON m.avatar_id = a.attachment_id
        WHERE m.user_id = ".$id."
order by         
m.user_id
        LIMIT 1
```